# Python object interaction

Tags: python, class, object, encapsulation, interaction

So, programming in Python 3, I've got a program with a problem whose essence I've distilled in this (non)functional piece of code:

```
class One:
    def __init__(self):
        self.var1 = 1

    def change(self):
        two.var2 = 5

class Two:
    def __init__(self):
        one = One()
        self.var2 = 2
        one.change()

two = Two()
```

The IDLE interpreter throws:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/-", line 15, in <module>
    two = Two()
  File "C:/-", line 12, in __init__
    one.change()
  File "C:/-", line 6, in change
    two.var2 = 5
NameError: name 'two' is not defined
```

Apparently, doing this instead:

```
class One:
    def __init__(self):
        self.var1 = 1

    def change(self):
        two.var2 = 5

class Two:
    def __init__(self):
        self.var2 = 2
        one.change()

one = One()
two = Two()
```

...doesn't help, as it gives me the exact same type of error. I really don't understand why this is happening... or how to structure it differently. I think the last time I had a problem like this I avoided it by nesting classes (rather messy and worked for only one level of nesting, as far as I can remember), but I'd really like to know how to make these two objects communicate with each other properly.

**Edit:** What I have is a program whose only line of code instantiates a main class, let's call it "Earth". In this program-object everything happens, included the instantiation of other classes; let's assume it's only one in this case, and call it "Moon". What I want to do is have this object Moon be able to change the Earth's states, its different variables.

Comment: Perhaps try to explain what are you trying to do may help us direct you into a solution, because currently the approach above looks flawed.

Comment: @AChampion Agreed, this may be an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I see it, you just have to pass to one.change() which object you want to change

```
class One:
    def __init__(self):
        self.var1 = 1

    def change(self, two):
        two.var2 = 5

class Two:
    def __init__(self):
        self.var2 = 2
        one.change(self)


one = One()
two = Two()
```

Comment: I don't think you can call `one.change(self)` without defining `one` first in the method. you will need to add `one = One()` before the `one.change(self)` line, ie within the method, not outside of it.

Answer (score 3):

You've misunderstood how python works. Until two is assigned, you cannot call `two.var2 = 5`. But you call that *while* you are instantiating (`two = Two()`), so the object you are building hasn't yet been assigned to `two`. Furthermore, it is generally poor design for classes to be accessing global scope.

Consider using Dependency Injection, where you give the class a local copy of the data it requires. This would take the form of `def __init__(self, dependency): self.dependency = dependency`. You may even be able to use the class `Two` as the dependency, creating Composition of objects rather than inheritance.

I touch on Inheritance, and it appears to be another solution: perhaps you mean to say `self.var2 = 5`, and to make your class `Two` inherit from `One`?

Answer (score 0):

"You've misunderstood how python works." I wouldn't have said it like that; I have a thin grasp of OOP in general, not of Python specifically. But I digress...

> "Until two is assigned, you cannot call two.var2 = 5. But you call
>   that while you are instantiating (two = Two()), so the object you are
>   building hasn't yet been assigned to two. Furthermore, it is generally
>   poor design for classes to be accessing global scope."

I edited my code to reflect this, or at least the way I understood it:

```
class One:
    def __init__(self):
        self.var1 = 1

    def change(self):
        two.var2 = 5

class Two:
    def __init__(self):
        self.var2 = 2
        self.program()

    def program(self):
        one = One()
        one.change()

two = Two()
```

I did this thinking the problem was that the function in the second object was called BEFORE the **init** of the first function concluded, but it still doesn't work. Anyway, tinkering some more, I tried this, which is probably the logical way to structure it:

```
class One:
    def __init__(self):
        self.var1 = 1

    def change(self):
        two.var2 = 5

class Two:
    def __init__(self):
        self.var2 = 2

one = One()
two = Two()
one.change()
```

...and it worked, as expected. I'll look into this and see if it can work if the last three lines of code can be part of the "program-object" I'm using and still work as well. Or perhaps I could scrap the "program-object" altogether and just have what few lines of code I had anyway in the main class be outside of it.

Regardless, what I needed was Josef's solution. Thank you! But what are you doing, exactly? By using "self" as the argument for the second object's method, what are you passing? The "object"? A reference to it...?

Answer (score 0):

You have two classes whose instances want to interact with each other. Each instance could keep a reference to the other but circular references are a dodgy business with python because they can confuse the reference counter and fail to delete objects when they are no longer used.

The `weakref` module lets you keep these relationships without messing up garbage collection. So,

```
import weakref

class One:
    def __init__(self, two):
        self.var1 = 1
        self.two = weakref.ref(two)

    def change(self):
        self.two().var2 = 5

class Two:
    def __init__(self):
        self.one = One(self)
        self.var2 = 2
        self.one.change()

two = Two()
print(two.var2)
```